# Can't we just transfer the gingerbread sourcecode from system to system? - Android

Tags: android, download, android-source

I need to work on android gingerbread sourcecode. I have linux (ubuntu) but no internet connection. My friend is already having the sourcecode downloaded to his system(ubuntu) from internet. Is it possible to copy and paste the code from his sytem to mine with out any issues running it? If it is possible, please specify the file paths if you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problems when copying source code from one machine to the other. No paths should be specified, it should work fine as is.

Both getting code from remote location via network or copying it form another machine are conceptually equivalent. After all both are just "copying" data to you computer.